# How to left pad a number with zeros in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

How can I output an integer in jinja2 as a string with a leading zero? So a variable containing 4 (integer) becomes "04"?

Comment: Use string formatting https://pyformat.info

Answer (score 26):

You can use the following to zero-pad numeric strings to be at least 2 characters long:

```
{{ '%02d' % your_variable }}
```

Some examples of input and output:

```
9   --> 09
10  --> 10
123 --> 123
x   --> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

---

Changing the `2` yields the results you would expect and things get a little more interesting when you make room for decimals. Using `'%05d'` gives the following results:

```
9      --> 00009
10     --> 00010
123    --> 00123
123456 --> 123456
34.2   --> 00034
34.8   --> 00034
```

---

Thanks to askaroni's comment for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Or you could use the `format` method: `{{ "{:02}".format(your_variable) }}` though it looks a bit contrived.